# Windows VM stuck in boot-loop because of "Uninstall Pending" security update

Tags: windows

## Setup

My machine is a VHD base VM with Windows Server 2012 installed.
Overnight the machine stops working and stuck in a boot loop.
Also, safe-mode doesn't work with the same behavior.

## Done so far

By using DISM tools with the offline image I tried the following:

---

`Dism /Image:F:\mount /Cleanup-Image /checkhealth`
`Dism /Image:F:\mount /Cleanup-Image /scanhealth`

**Result:**
no problems found

---

`Dism /Image:F:\mount /Cleanup-Image /startComponentCleanup`

**Result:**
Could not be finished because of pending operations.

---

`Dism /Image:F:\mount /Cleanup-Image /RevertPendingActions`

**Result:**
Successful closed

---

`dism /image:F:\mount /get-packages /Format:Table`

**Result:**
All packages listed are "Installed" except of one in state "Uninstall Pending"

```
Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~9600.18528.1.5 | Uninstall Pending | Security Update | 31.08.2020 03:06
```

---

## Question

To resolve the status of package in state "Uninstall Pending" a restart is needed.
But trying to restart will result in a boot loop.

What can I do here to get the machine up and running again?
Is there any way to cancel this package in "Uninstall Pending" state without a restart?

Comment: Restart the Server at a convenient time. Normally a restart will clear a pending uninstall during the restart.  Try at that point to boot into Safe Mode and see if you can get the uninstall done that way

Comment: I tried already. Both normal and safe mode showing shortly the windows logo with loading circle. Then the screen stays black for 30sec and  booting again. Package stays in the same state.

Comment: I do not know what way out of that. If you can put the Server OS on a USB drive, can you launch a Server Repair?